# How to Generate multiple rows from single row data with split/explode function - scala sql/Apache Pyspark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

One or more pairs of values will be in the ContentGroupsListText attribute, separated by semi-colons. For each pair of values, take the one to the right of the hyphen and generate a record for that CompanyCode. For example, if ContentGroupsListText = GT01-5636;GT01-7212, records would be generated for CompanyCode 5636 and 7212. All attributes other than CompanyCode are duplicated.
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
      `Name          |  ContentGroupsListText`                                  |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
  `Maxwell`        |`GT01-5636;GT02-7212`                                         
  `Leonard`        |`Hx017-5621;GY01-H;GL01-3336;GT09-0012`                       
  `Phoebe`         |`LT02-5636;GT02-IU;GT09-6012`                                 
  `Suresh`         |`GAx01-5626;GY01-1112;GL01-5336;GT09-9912;GT09-1112;GT09-0912`

I want my data in this form:

```
+--------------------+--------------------
       Name          |  CompanyCode|
+--------------------+--------------------
    Maxwell          |5636
    Maxwell          |7212
    Leonard          |5621
    Leonard          |H
    Leonard          |3336
    Leonard          |0012
    Phoebe           |5636
    Phoebe           |IU
    Phoebe           |6012
    Suresh           |5626
    Suresh           |1112
    Suresh           |5336
    Suresh           |9912
    Suresh           |1112
    Suresh           |0912
```

Comment: isn't this exactly same as [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73453464/8279585)?

Comment: Yeah, but I have another database and need to join these company codes on the Name Column of that particular database. But when I got the company codes from ContentGroupListText the name column is not repeating the values when I am creating the CompanyCodes.

Comment: are you saying the answers mentioned there did not work for you? when i checked, they work fine on this example data as well. but you'd obviously have to select the column, i.e. add the name in the `select`

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine but the problem is regex can't be applied on "IU" and "H".

Comment: last i checked, there are 2 solutions mentioned there - one of them is non-regex

Answer (score 1):

I did it in parts but I don't know if it's the most optimized way:

```
df = df.withColumn('splitted', F.explode(F.split(F.col('ContentGroupsListText'), ';', -1)))
df = df.withColumn('CompanyCode', F.split(F.col('splitted'), '-', 2)[1])
df = df.drop("ContentGroupsListText", "splitted")
```